# How can I mimic a Javascript "spread operator" in C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, recursion

I am following a tutorial on Dynamic Programming on youtube to understand more about Recursive functions, and I am stuck where a spread operator is used.

**Code in JavaScript**

```
const howSum = (targetSum, numbers) =>{
    if(targetSum === 0) return [];
    if(targetSum < 0) return null;

    for(let num of numbers){
           const remainder = targetSum - num;
           const remainderResult = howSum(remainder, numbers);
            if(remainderResult != null){
                 return [...remainderResult, num];
            } 
    }
    return null;

};
```

**This is the code in C# where I'm trying to replicate the function**

```
class HowSumSlow {

    static dynamic HowSum(int targetSum, int[] numbers)
    {
            
        if (targetSum == 0) return numbers;
        if (targetSum < 0) return null;

        
        foreach( var num in numbers){
            var remainder = targetSum - num;
            int[] remainderResult = HowSum(remainder, numbers);

            if (remainderResult != null) { 
                //Code here//
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    static void Main(string[] arg) {
        int[] numbers = new int[] { 2, 3 };
        Console.WriteLine(HowSum(7, numbers));
    }
    
}
```

EDIT: <strike>Should I use a Dictionary and use a key? I don't understand how to work my way around this one.</strike>

```
  static Dictionary<int, int[]> spread = new Dictionary<int, int[]>();
            
        static dynamic HowSum(int targetSum, int[] numbers){
        ...
            if(spread.ContainsKey(remainderResult)){
                return spread[remainderResult];
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**

```
class HowSumSlow {

    static int[] HowSum(int targetSum, int[] numbers)
    {
        int[] empty = new int[] { };
        if (targetSum == 0) return empty;
        if (targetSum < 0) return null;

        
        
        foreach( var num in numbers){
            var remainder = targetSum - num;
            int[] remainderResult = HowSum(remainder, numbers);

            if (remainderResult != null){
                return remainderResult.Append(num).ToArray();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    static void Main(string[] arg) {
        int[] numbers = new int[] { 2, 3, 5 };
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", HowSum(8, numbers)));
    }


}
```

Comment: `[...remainderResult, num]` is just taking the array `remainderResult`, and creating a new array by appending `num`. You can do the same in C# with e.g. `remainderResult.Append(num).ToArray()`. I'm not sure why you're using `dynamic` though...

Comment: Given that `[...remainderResult, num]` is just `remainderResult.concat(num)`, I don't think you need to mimic spread, rather than just do the same operation. Which is immutably adding an item to array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no spread operator in c#, you could use the `Append` method in the `System.Linq` namespace. As this returns an `IEnumerable<T>` you'll also need to call `ToArray()` afterwards.

This line in JS

```
return [...remainderResult, num];
```

Could be the following in c#

```
return remainderResult.Append(num).ToArray();
```

Note that your method always returns `int[]` or null, so the return type should be `int[]` not `dynamic`!

Comment: It's giving me "System.Int32[]" in the terminal. Is there a way to print out the array?

Comment: @Ilian Iterate it and write out each element of the array

Comment: Or e.g. `string.Join(", ", array)`

Comment: Indeed, something like `Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",",HowSum(7, numbers)));` - see here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xNBcDS

Comment: @canton7 so I tried doing  `Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", HowSum(7, numbers)));` but it's giving me `2,3,3,2,2` , instead of `2,2,3`

Comment: Your `if (targetSum == 0) return numbers;` is wrong -- the javascript version returns an empty array

Comment: @canton7 Thank you! I didn't catch that part. I'm not sure if this is the right way, but I changed the top part to `int[] empty = new int[] { };
        if (targetSum == 0) return empty;` Would that possibly be right?

Comment: Sure, or just `new int[0]`

Comment: @Jamiec I looked at your code, and I was wondering if I had to include `using System.Linq`.  I am using C#: .NET Core 5.0.103 at the moment

Comment: @Ilian yes. As I said in the answer

Comment: @Jamiec Oh, okay. I was just wondering because it didn't seem to matter whether I included it or not.

Comment: @Ilian you sure? It won't compile without `using System.Linq` because yo're using methods from that namespace. See: https://dotnetfiddle.net/UFlcsq

Comment: @Jamiec Oh, for some reason, it worked without the Linq namespace in my Visual Studio IDE. Maybe I was mistaken

Answer (score 3):

C# 12 introduced a spread operator that is similar to Javascript. It is still under preview but it will be in available in stable channel along with .Net 8

Their example is

```
int[] row0 = [1, 2, 3];
int[] row1 = [4, 5, 6];
int[] row2 = [7, 8, 9];
int[] single = [..row0, ..row1, ..row2];
```

See more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-12#collection-expressions).